# Lots of svchost.exe processes are running on my system

Tags: windows-7

There are multiple `svchost.exe` processes running on my system (about 10-11) using up 99% CPU usage in my system.

Can these be stopped, is it likely I have a virus?

Comment: See this post if you suspect an infection....http://superuser.com/questions/100360/what-to-do-if-my-computer-is-infected-by-a-virus-or-a-malware/157533#157533

Answer (score 5):

### What is svchost.exe?

`svchost.exe` stands short for a service host executable, they might or might not host a virus service.

> Svchost.exe is a process on your computer that hosts, or contains, other individual services that Windows uses to perform various functions. For example, Windows Defender uses a service that is hosted by a svchost.exe process.
>
> There can be multiple instances of svchost.exe running on your computer, with each instance containing different services. One instance of svchost.exe might host a single service for a program, and another instance might host several services related to Windows. You can use Task Manager to view which services are running under each instance of svchost.exe.
>
> — Source: [Microsoft - What is svchost.exe?](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/What-is-svchost-exe)

### Why could it use a lot of CPU Power?

Services do things in the background on your computer, you can check that in the [Resource Monitor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Monitor):

1. Run `resmon.exe` from a command prompt as an administrator, or through the Task Manager.

[image: Task Manager]

2. Click on the **CPU tab** in the Resource Monitor, **sort by the CPU column**.
3. Checkmark the highest CPU `svchost.exe` processes, look in Services which consume CPU.

[image: Resource Monitor]

Answer (score 2):

svchost.exe are normal processes on win7. it is also normal to have multiple running at once. But what is abnormal is that they are taking up so much CPU. does this happen all the time? try restarting. It could just be a system error stuck in a loop.

but it could also be a virus, they like to pretend to be windows processes. If so, do some virus cleaning.

though to immediately stop the processes you could always just go ctrl+alt+delete and stop services